# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart, datamodel

I'm trying to follow along this 2 year old Fluter tutorial on Udemy its based on a ride sharing app, but I've come to a halt. am receiving this error

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try defining the operator '[]'.

My flutter sdk version is 2.11.0

```
User.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    id = snapshot.key;
    phone = snapshot.value['phone'];//here is the error
    email = snapshot.value['email'];//here is the error
    fullName = snapshot.value['fullname'];//here is the error

    //phone = snap
  }
```

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class User {
  String fullName;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String id;

  User({
    this.fullName,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.id,
  });

  User.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    id = snapshot.key;
    phone = snapshot.value['phone'];
    email = snapshot.value['email'];
    fullName = snapshot.value['fullname'];

    //phone = snap
  }
}
```

Comment: try `(snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>)['phone']`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `DataSnapshot`